# HDFS Java Client API - Get INode from Path and get Path from INode

Tags: hdfs

I'm trying to track movements of files, so that if a file is moved I can see that it's moved.  Right now the only reference to a file I can see via the standard API is the path, which can change.

Is it possible to retrieve the INodeID of a file from the [java filesystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html), and map the INodeID to a path and vice versa?

If not, is there another API that allows this sort of access?